# Adding a keyboard listener in Actionscript 2 to entire flash movie

Tags: flash, event-handling, actionscript-2, keyboard-events

I've been poking around quite a bit for a way to effectively use AS2 to detect a spacebar press across the entirety of the .swf, regardless of what movie clip is in focus. I've found several claimed solutions that were either for AS3 or for AS2 but not doing precisely what I needed. After adapting what I'd found, nothing thus far has produced a single detected spacebar press. Can anyone suggest alternatives? I feel like it's something really obvious and I'm missing it!

Here's what I've tried thus far (located within the first and only frame on the timeline):
1)

```
var stageListener:Object = new Object();
stageListener.onKeyUp = function() {
    if(Key.getAscii() == 32){
        trace("spaceup");
        dostuff;
    }
};
Stage.addListener(stageListener);
```

2)

```
stage.onKeyUp = function() {
    if(Key.getAscii() == 32){
        trace("spaceup");
        dostuff;
    }
};
```

3)

```
_root.onKeyUp = function() {
    if(Key.getAscii() == 32){
        trace("spaceup");
        dostuff;
    }
};
```

4)

```
Main.stage.onKeyUp = function() {
    if(Key.getAscii() == 32){
        trace("spaceup");
        dostuff;
    }
};
```

5) Attached one of these to every display-level interactive movie clip in the swf. Still nothing!

```
this.onKeyUp = function() {
    if(Key.getAscii() == 32){
        trace("spaceup");
        dostuff;
    }
};
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close with your first try.  The `Key` object is where you attach the listener, not stage.

```
var keyListener:Object = new Object();
keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {
   if(Key.getCode() == 32){
       //do something here for space bar press
   }
};
Key.addListener(keyListener);
```

AS2 is pretty vintage... I hope you have a good reason for using it instead of AS3

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm, so thank you! As for AS2, I've noticed that it is quite vintage, but my work concerns modifying code licensed from someone else, so unfortunately I can only add to the original, rather than modify or refactor it.